# What is the best way in Python to loop over a list back to front?

Tags: python, list, iteration

Right now I do it like this:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)-1, -1, -1):
    # ...
```

but I am wondering if we have a better way with clearer meaning.

Comment: `for i in my_list[::-1]` would also work but that will create a new list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`reversed()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
for elem in reversed(my_list):
```

An object can support efficient reverse iteration by offering a [`__reversed__()` special method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__); list objects implement this method to support reverse iteration efficiently. Otherwise, the normal sequence protocol ([`object.__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and [`object.__len__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__)) must be implemented.

Note that this doesn't create a new list object; it produces an *iterator*, an object that tracks position in the list as you loop over it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: if no `__reversed__` method is found, it stores `pos = len(object)` and each time you call `next()` on it, it'll decrement `pos` and access `object[pos]`. If `pos` is 0, `StopIteration` is raised. If `__reversed__` is available, the result of that method is returned, where that object must be an iterator.

Comment: so internally it is basically a loop starting from `len(l)-1`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: see the [C source code for the `reversed()` object](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/83b75b016c77/Objects/enumobject.c#l214); and perhaps the [object `list.__reversed__()` returns](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/83b75b016c77/Objects/listobject.c#l2947).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yes, but because it is an iterator all this is handled in C code, and specialist objects can return specialist reversed iterators. The [`range()` object does this](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dc699f150fd3/Objects/rangeobject.c#l1163), for example.